# changing textures using nineveh gl frsmework

Tags: ios

If i am trying to change the another texture when the previous one is still in progress application is crashing..

Here is my code.

-(IBAction)changeTexture:(id)sender{

```
self.text = [arrayEyes objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
NGLTexture *texture;
texture = [NGLTexture texture2DWithFile:self.text];

NGLMaterialMulti *material = (NGLMaterialMulti *)mesh.material;

[[material materialWithName:@"lambert16SG"] setDiffuseMap:texture];

mesh.material = material;
[mesh compileCoreMesh];
```

}

Comment: this may help http://vimeo.com/24973692

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that this code is hit right at the beginning of program execution.  So for a bit there the model is still being loaded in a background thread.

So it's likely NGLTexture is being assigned to the mesh's material while it's being processed in another thread.   You may run into assignment issues that will either throw an exception or outright crash.  Try waiting for the model loader to finish processing before making assignments to it.  Look up the NGLMeshDelegate protocol and try making the assignment in your -meshLoadingDidFinish: handler.